# Protobuf-net not serializing List

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am currently experimenting with protobuf-net (v3.0.29) and trying to serialize/deserialize some simple classes. From the minimal working example, I do not understand why protobuf-net serializes/deserializes the simple `List<int> Value` to a list with no elements.

```
    public enum BigEnum { One, Two }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Container
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public BigEnum Parameter { get; private set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public List<int> Value { get; set; }
        public Container()
        {
            Parameter = BigEnum.One;
            Value = new List<int>();
        }
    }
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Container data = new Container();
            data.Value.Add(-1);
            data.Value.Add(1);

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize<Container>(memStream, data);
            var result = Serializer.Deserialize<Container>(memStream);
        }
    }
```

This protobuf-file was generated by *Serializer.GetProto()* and looks fine to me.
How can we process `List<int> Value` correctly and can protobuf-net handle more complex structures like
`List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>` or `Dictionary<int,double>` within a class?
There are some very old posts for protobuf-net with dictionaries around but I don't know what's the current state.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package NetCoreProtobuf;

enum BigEnum {
   One = 0;
   Two = 1;
}
message Container {
   BigEnum Parameter = 1;
   repeated int32 Value = 2 [packed = false];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: you didn't rewind the stream, so it read from the *current* position - at the end of the stream, with zero bytes to read. It happens to be the case that zero bytes is *perfectly valid* in protobuf, so it can't really raise an
exception here, as you might be entirely correct in deserializing zero bytes.

```cs
Serializer.Serialize<Container>(memStream, data);
memStream.Position = 0;
var result = Serializer.Deserialize<Container>(memStream);
```

Or simpler: use the `DeepClone` method:

```cs
var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(data);
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. In my usecase used windows NamedPipes as a memory stream but finally I dropped it and go for [NetMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq). Anyway this answear is correct.